# Conditional formatting cells in range if the cell value exist in a different column

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

In Google spreadsheet, we have column A which is an input list. Other columns from B to G are filled list. Filled list cells should highlight when cell value matches with input list.
The problem is I can not use MATCH as matching is with the range not column or row.

Here is the expected result. [image: expected result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definetely can use Match. But you need to use it with ISERROR & NOT formula.
You need apply the following Conditional formatting to the entire range starting from B1.

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,$A:$A,0)))
```

**Note:** if you copy the formula exactly, you need to apply it to the Range starting from B! For it work.

Comment: Sorry sir but this is not working. a little help will be beneficial.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j2rYrQkkAgXrMCpgWdT6sNoZYR9Xn6QtwA9wfODJyUA/edit#gid=2085328934

Comment: Its done. You have not used the "NOT" formula in your conditional formatting. And I had a small correction in the formula too.

Comment: I've opened the sheet linked by @TechCare99 and copied the formula to my sheet. And i got error that formula is not valid - my google sheet require to remove equation on the beggining .... this conditional formatting doesn't work ...
I want to format my customers by list that is in another sheet - Customers!$A:$A - and can;t get it to work...

Comment: @Bri.H. based on your regional settings, semi-colon(`;`) is used instead of comma(`,`), Like this - `=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(B1;$A:$A;0)))`

Comment: @Gangula  thank you, but when i open his sheet, and copied to my drive GSuite adapt formulas to my region. Yet formula wasn't working :(

Comment: Try breaking down the formula one by one and see where does it result in error. Google Sheets should also help you out by displaying the error